# Identify duplicate characters in a String and replace them

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge

Found a [JavaScript assignment on Codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54b42f9314d9229fd6000d9c):

> The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where
>   each character in the new string is '(' if that character appears only
>   once in the original string, or ')' if that character appears more
>   than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when
>   determining if a character is a duplicate.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> ```
> "din" => "((("
> "recede" => "()()()"
> "Success" => ")())())"
> "(( @" => "))(("
> ```

I did the assignment in Java, and came up with below code. I want to know is this the write way to code or is there a better way? If so please let me know.

```
private static String duplicateEncode(String word) {
    String encodeString = "";
    String decodedString = word.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < decodedString.length(); i++) {

        if (decodedString.substring(i + 1, decodedString.length())
                .contains(String.valueOf(decodedString.charAt(i)))
                || decodedString.substring(0, i).contains(String.valueOf(decodedString.charAt(i)))) {
            encodeString += ")";
        } else {
            encodeString += "(";
        }

    }
    return encodeString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, nullbyte is exactly right about the use of a StringBuilder: using `a += b` for Strings roughly equals `new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString()` under the hood and thus is a quite expensive operation.

Then, your method to check whether a given charcter exists in the string after a given index is `s.substring(i).contains(ch)` which again creates a superfluos string object via the substring-call. Instead, simply use `s.indexOf(ch, i)` to find the next index of ch after the given starting index (returns -1 for "not found").

Additionally, you might consider nullbyte's suggestion to hold the seen-or-not-seen status in a set, which also was my first intuition when reading the exercise. (Right now, you have runtime complexity of O(n^2) which you could reduce to O(n)). You only have to somehow come up with a method to revisit the first character, maybe by not using  a set but by usign a map from character to number of occurrences or something like that.

Naming: why `decodedString`? This is not decoded in any way, this is just lowercase word. I can live with `encodeString` (or probably better encoded), but decodedString does not look right and does not give the reader any clue about the variable's contents.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a better solution using a hash map:

```
 public static String encode(String input) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final Map<Character, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
        char ch = Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(index));
        if(indexMap.containsKey(ch)) {
            int previous = indexMap.get(ch);
            builder.replace(previous, previous+1, ")");
            builder.append(')');
        }else {
            indexMap.put(ch, index);
            builder.append('(');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It requires **O(n) time** and **O(n) additional space**, but it's way faster than yours. Also, try using a `StringBuilder` if you append strings in a loop.

Comment: The above code will fail if the first character is coming twice. For eg: if my string is abca, i am expecting an output )((). But the above code will print ((().

Comment: Not worth my karma to downvote this, but I don't consider "I can do it better, here's some code" a review.

Comment: @mtj Well, I think it's not worth pointing out, but the OP's question is: `I want to know if is this the right way to code or if  there is a better way?` Is this how you read it? First of all, it was not my intention to hurt someone else's feelings by "showing off" with a better solution. Secondly, there's really nothing to review, and I think I've pointed (as well as you have) the main points in my post. I could have done it more explicitly though.

Comment: @SKV Ha! that's a good catch. Thanks. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String encode(String input) {
 input= input.toLowerCase(); //ignoring case
 StringBuilder myNewString = new StringBuilder(); // for holding new String
 for(char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
   if(StringUtils.countMatches(input, ch) > 1){ // more than 1 condition
       myNewString.append(")");
   }else{ // not repeating chars
      myNewString.append("(");
   }
 }
   myNewString.toString();
}
```

I am using StringUtils class from Apache Commons project.
So need add this to your import: 
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

Comment: Same as I already commented at nullbyte's answer. This is not a review. BTW, what is StringUtils?

Comment: oh forgot to mention, StringUtils is an Apache Commons project. Edited my original post and added package. Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a little bit more concise solution than the original one. What's the time complexity of the `StringUtils.countMatches()` method?  It's definitely `O(n)` which doesn't make it any better. You used a `StringBuilder` though.